# WYSIWYG text editor showing not good in query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wysiwyg

I have a problem i integreted the CKeditor to my CMS, and when i copy some text to the query show me a `<\h2>` `<\p>` after a

, then if a try to delete those statament , after i deleted it showed me on page more `<\h2>` `<\p>`

```
<\p>

 <\p>

 <\p>

 <\p>
```

page.php

```
// Query the body section for the proper page
    $stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT pagebody FROM travel WHERE link = ?');
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $pageid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        // do something with $row
        $body = htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($row['pagebody'])); //pentru caractere speciale

    } <?php echo $body; ?>
```

//edit_page

```
<?php
// You may want to obtain refering site name that this post came from for security purposes here
// exit the script if it is not from your site and script
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$pid = $_POST['pid'];
$titlu = $_POST['titlu'];
$link = $_POST['link'];
$keyword = $_POST['keyword'];
$poza = $_POST['poza'];
$descriere = $_POST['descriere'];
$data = $_POST['data'];
$pagebody = $_POST['pagebody'];
// Filter Function -------------------------------------------------------------------
function filterFunction ($var) { 
    $var = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($var));
    $var = str_replace("/", "\\\\", $var);
    $var = preg_replace("~/~", "\\\\", $var);

    return $var; 
} 
$titlu = filterFunction($titlu);
$link = filterFunction($link);
$keyword = filterFunction($keyword);
$poza = filterFunction($poza);
$descriere = filterFunction($descriere);
$data = filterFunction($data);
$pagebody = filterFunction($pagebody);
// End Filter Function --------------------------------------------------------------
include_once "../conx.php";
// Add the updated info into the database table
$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE travel SET titlu=?, link=?, keywords=?, poza=?, descriere=?, pagebody=?, data=? WHERE id = ?");
    // TODO check that $stmt creation succeeded
    // "s" means the database expects a string
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssssss", $titlu, $link, $keyword, $poza, $descriere, $pagebody, $data, $pid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's due to this line in your PHP code:

```
 $var = str_replace("/", "\\\\", $var);
```

Comment: and what is the right answer? what i i need to change ?

Comment: This is just a guess, but I think that you shouldn't use that filter function on content that you want to display as HTML.

Comment: Indeed i removed those line from the content variable and now works